# ssh remote command hung up on lost connection

Tags: ssh

I am trying to monitor the execution of a service on a remote PC and execute functions depending on the result. So the function should be something like this:

- If service "X" is running on system 1, do nothing on system 2
- If service "X" is *not running* on system 1, start service "Y" on system 2

Therefore I wanted to use `pgrep` over `ssh` like this:

```
ssh root@10.0.0.1 pgrep -x "service"
```

If the connection between both systems gets cut during execution of above commandline my script gets stuck. If the connection was cut before execution it fails with an error as expected.

Executing ssh with `-o ConnectTimeout=1` didn't fix the problem because the SSH connection was established at the point the connection gets cut.

I am expecting the connection to break eventually and executing my script further on. But even after several minutes the script is hung up on this remote executed command.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ssh configuration options that are designed to help the ssh client detect a broken connection to the ssh server on a remote computer.  They are `-o ServerAliveInterval=15` and `-o ServerAliveCountMax=3`.  The interval is the number of seconds between probes by the client to request an answer from the server (remote computer), and the count max is how many consecutive failures will make the client decide the connection is broken.

The two values above will take about 45 seconds for the client to detect a problem and end the session (returning an error code to your script).  If you set the count max to 0 (the default) it will not send the probes to detect a problem and it can take 10 minutes or more.

In my opinion setting the combination to less than 45 seconds increases the risk of your ssh client disconnecting too soon and interrupting your monitoring when the network was slow rather than the connection broken.  Setting the interval to more than 60-120 seconds has the risk that network devices like firewalls will tear down a connection that's idle instead of broken (and break your connection).

(I didn't discuss the `TCPKeepAlive` option because it's not as useful for detecting broken connections or keeping connections alive as the `ServerAlive*` options)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `timeout` command to wrap the `ssh` in a time limited context

```
pid=$(timeout 10s ssh -n root@10.0.0.1 'pgrep -x service' 2>/dev/null)
ss=$?

case "$ss" in
    124)    echo "Timeout" >&2 ;;
    1[23?)  echo "Something went badly wrong ($ss)" >&2 ;;
    0)      echo "All is well" >&2 ;;
    *)      echo "An error occurred with the remote execution ($ss)" >&2 ;;
esac

if [ -z "$pid" ]
then
    echo "No result from ssh pgrep" >&2
fi
```

The documentation (`man timeout`) defines the duration as "*a floating point number with an optional suffix: `s` for seconds (the default), `m` for minutes, `h` for hours or `d` for days.*".